# How to import contacts from the contact Framework ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, ios9, contacts

How to add multiple phone number using Contact Framework iOS 9

```
CNMutableContact *contact = [test mutableCopy];
CNLabeledValue *homePhone_1 = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelHome value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:@"019312-555-1212"]];
CNLabeledValue * homePhone_2 = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelHome value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:@"312-555-1219"]];
[contact.phoneNumbers addObjectsFromArray:@[homePhone_1]];
[contact.phoneNumbers addObjectsFromArray:@[homePhone_2]];
CNSaveRequest *request = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];
[request updateContact:contact];
```

Please help guys. This is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try with following `code`.

```
- (void) addContact {

    CNMutableContact * contact = [CNMutableContact new];
    contact.middleName = @"Testmiddle";
    contact.contactType = CNContactTypePerson;
    contact.givenName = @"TestGivenname";
    contact.familyName = @"Taken";
    CNLabeledValue *homePhone_1 = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelHome value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:@"019312-555-1212"]];
    CNLabeledValue * homePhone_2 = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelWork value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:@"312-555-1219"]];
    contact.phoneNumbers = @[homePhone_1, homePhone_2];
    CNSaveRequest *request = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];
    [request addContact:contact toContainerWithIdentifier:nil];

    @try {
        CNContactStore * store = [CNContactStore new];
        [store executeSaveRequest:request error:nil];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"description =  %@",[exception description]);

    }
}
```

For `update` contact you need to use following `code`.

**Fetching contact encapsulate I/O operation so that why i recommended that you use them on background threads. If needed, you can safely send immutable fetch results back to the main thread**

```
- (void)updateContact {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

        CNContactStore * store = [CNContactStore new];
        NSArray * arrFetchedcontact = [NSArray array];

        @try {
            arrFetchedcontact = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:[CNContact predicateForContactsMatchingName:@"TestGivenname"] keysToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CNContactGivenNameKey",@"CNContactFamilyNameKey",CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, nil] error:nil];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"description =  %@",[exception description]);
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if([arrFetchedcontact count] > 0){

                CNMutableContact * contact = [[arrFetchedcontact objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
                NSMutableArray * arrNumbers = [[contact phoneNumbers] mutableCopy];
                CNLabeledValue * homePhone_2 = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelOther value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:@"33333333333"]];
                [arrNumbers addObject:homePhone_2];

                contact.phoneNumbers = arrNumbers;

                CNSaveRequest *request = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];
                [request updateContact:contact];

                @try {
                    [store executeSaveRequest:request error:nil];
                }
                @catch (NSException *exception) {
                    NSLog(@"description =  %@",[exception description]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: How to get existing phone number CNLabeledValue and how to append this two homePhone_1 and homePhone_1 with existing phone number.please advice Abhishek Sharma

Comment: My console show the following line 

(
    "<CNLabeledValue: 0x145693b0: identifier=F08EEB0F-C512-47DA-A0F2-EDC66E488108, label=_$!<Home>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x14568a30: countryCode=in, digits=0193125551212>>",
    "<CNLabeledValue: 0x145681a0: identifier=848C0940-C2D9-41D5-89D5-04D9880F824D, label=_$!<Home>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x145692f0: countryCode=in, digits=3125551219>>"
)

From this i need to convert to CNLabeledValue.please advice.

Comment: it is working fine.But i don't know the count of phone number.it is based upon the contact we selected. Abhishek Sharma

Comment: @VenkaTeshuser5397700 Print `contact` object in console you will get idea how many number's is added in contact.

And if you think answer is usefull then mark as right so other can utilize it.

Comment: But i need to add one phone number to existing contact at same time keep  the existing phone number also.here we replace the contact phone number.contact.phoneNumbers = @[homePhone_1, homePhone_2]; how to do this

Comment: sorry Abhishek Sharma my Reputation (1).can't mark answer as right.